# Why do the policemen in Batman Beyond have a 5 emblem on their uniforms?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, batman-beyond

Why do the police in Batman Beyond all have a 5 on their uniforms?

[image: police]

Comment: They all share the same... rank. 5th.......unit of rank.

Answer (score 13):

I'll have to dig through the commentaries to confirm this, but according to [this post](http://lurkerfaqs.com/boards/400-current-events/65712462/), someone claims:

> My friend also suggested that it's a pun: a five in a circle meaning 5-O

and then

> Yea its 5-O I heard it on the commentary on one of DVDs.

The more prevalent theory is that it denotes the precinct they serve (though, why they're all out of the 5th precinct would still be a mystery).

Comment: What does 5-O mean?

Comment: In the US, [it is slang for 'the police'](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=5-0).

Comment: I have heard of the TV show, but I never knew what the 5-O part stood for...

Comment: Police will often refer to their precincts like that. '5-O' for 50th or '3-O' for 30th, etc. You can see this in a lot of modern TV shows like Law & Order. What the '5-O' stood for specifically in Hawaii 5-O is up to debate. A common theory is that it was named that after the fact that it was the 50th state.

Comment: In the new continuity, 5-O was chosen by the squad itself... It's hawaiian pidgin for state police, and has become nationwide slang for police due to the wide popularity of the original Hawaii 5-O.

Comment: @NaftaliakaNeal There was a police show set in Hawaii, and Hawaii was the 50th state. Often, the letter "o" is used to denote the number zero, so the show was called "Hawaii Five-0". But the connection to Hawaii being the 50th state wasn't clear, so people started treating the "Five-0" as referring to police.